# model.save() timing issue in ember-data with belongsTo relationship

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have two models (`source` and `problem`) and I am saving an instance with relation to the other when `click` is triggered through the UI.

```coffee
App.SourcesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  actions:
    addProblem: (source) ->
      problem = @store.createRecord('problem',
        detectedOn: new Date(),
        source: source
      )
      problem.save().then (problem) ->
          # handle success
        ,(e) ->
          # handle error
      false
```

I am certain that `source` is present when inside the `addProblem` action, but when the client actually serializes the model and sends the request, `detectedOn` attribute is present, but `source_id` is nowhere to be found.

Now, here is the interesting part.

When I wrap the save code in `setTimeout`, both `detectedOn` and `source_id` do get sent to the server:

```coffee
App.SourcesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  actions:
    addProblem: (source) ->
      problem = @store.createRecord('problem',
        detectedOn: new Date(),
        source: source
      )
      setTimeout ->
        problem.save().then (problem) ->
            # handle success
          ,(e) ->
            # handle error
        , 1
      false
```

It seems to me that it's a timing issue within Ember's cycle, or perhaps I am missing something?

How can I get rid of the `setTimeout`? I should not be doing this every time I save.

Comment: Will you show the Class definition for Problem?

Comment: I've noticed this (I think this is a bug with Ember), but can you try to resolve the `source` before saving? Like `problem.get('source').then(function () { problem.save(); })`

Comment: what do your models look like (are they async true?)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the inverse relationship manually when resolving the promise.The following should work for you:

```
App.SourcesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  actions:
    addProblem: (source) ->
      problem = @store.createRecord('problem',
        detectedOn: new Date(),
        source: source
      )
      problem.save().then (problem) ->
          source.get('problems').addObject(problem)
        ,(e) ->
          # handle error
      false
```

Comment: Wouldn't that dirty the `source` object?